# Boy cat turned out to be a girl - do we need to change the name ending?

Tags: género, nombres-propios, números

We were given a kitten on Cinco de Mayo, and told it was male. We named him "Cinc**o**". Then the vet told us that he is a she! So we figured we might need to call her "Cinc**a**". As in Robert**o** -> Robert**a**. It doesn't matter that it wouldn't mean "five" any more. Would love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Locked comments from question and answers because of repeated extended discussions. It is abundantly clear to everyone that cardinal numbers are invariable in Spanish. Please **do not** start another extended discussion on this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking whether there are masculine names that end in "a" and feminine names that end in "o", then **there are**. For example:

- *Borja* and *Bautista* are masculine names ending in "a"
- *Consuelo* and *Amparo* are feminine names ending in "o".

So calling a female cat "Cinco" would not violate any rule. No rule says that nouns or names ending in "o" must be masculine and nouns or names ending in "a" must be feminine. That is just something that happens in the vast majority of the cases.

"Cinca" is, by the way, the name of a [river in Spain](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%ADo_Cinca).

Apart from that, the name of your cat is of course your choice. "Cinco" will sound like a number, "Cinca" not necessarily.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to combine the number five, because that is the day you were given the cat, and its female sex, you can use the ordinal number which, unlike the cardinal one, varies according to gender:

- Mi gata se llama "Quinta" porque me la regalaron el quinto día de mayo.

Answer (score 2):

Spanish names are usually O for boys and A for girls. Juan/Juana.

There are a few exceptions as posted by wimi above.

However, numbers in Spanish are **invariable** so *cinca* **is not** the "feminine of cinco".

Uno, dos, tres, cuatro, cinco, seis= **Invariable**.

*Cinca* is merely attempting to make feminine something that is invariable.

You can name your cat whatever you want.

The connection to Cinco de Mayo will be lost if you call her Cinca.

Comment: "O for boys and A for girls. Juan / Juana" Eh, where is the O in Juan?

Comment: @RubioRic The "o" will only appear in the diminutive "Juanito" :)

Comment: @Gustavson You're absolutely right.